# How to get network speed in the ADB shell without using iwconfig

Tags: c, linux, embedded-linux, marshmallow, adb

i'm trying to get the bit rate using the iwconfig for the wireless wlan0 but it is no getting it
and also tried to get with file sys/class/net/wlan0/speed it is also no getting the answer

```
cat sys/class/net/wlan0/speed                                 
/system/bin/sh: cat: sys/class/net/wlan0/speed: Invalid argument

:/ # iwconfig                                                     sit0 no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan0     no wireless extensions.

tap0      no wireless extensions.
```

it is connected to wlan0 but not showing

iwant the command that can get the bit rate for the wlan0 and also for the sim interface can anyone help me with this

Comment: does `cat /sys/...` make any difference? (note the leading `/` char). Good luck.

Comment: no it doesn't make any differece  .....# cat /sys/class/net/wlan0/speed                                
/system/bin/sh: cat: /sys/class/net/wlan0/speed: Invalid argument